# Is it possible to 'randomly' select a row from a table using ormlite?

Tags: android, random, ormlite

I would like to select a row from a table, but I only want to get one row and the row will be selected randomly.

Comment: I haven't used ORMlite. But you can do something like selecting random id and then reading that id from the table.

Comment: Let me try that. Thank you. If you have some code samples or something I will be very grateful. I do have to keep in mind the number of rows selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to select a row from a table, but I only want to get one row and the row will be selected randomly.

There isn't any special method calls which do this but there are ways that you can use the `QueryBuilder` to accomplish this.

If you have a numerical id, something like like should work:

```
qb = dao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().raw("id >= (ABS(RANDOM()) % MAX(id) + 1)");
entity = qb.queryForFirst();
```

[Sqlite `RANDOM()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random) returns a large positive or negative integer.  `ABS()` makes it just positive, `MAX(id)` allows us to then mod by the maximum `id` value.  The `+1` allows us to actually choose the max `id` row.

Comment: This answer is certainly the best way to tackle the problem at hand now that I thought about it and read your input on my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use queryRaw:

```
Relation result = null;
String query = "SELECT * from relations ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
try {
    result = queryRaw(query, getRawRowMapper()).getFirstResult();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this maybe I'll try this next time

Comment: It's surprising that there is a RANDOM() keyword in sqlite though

Answer (score 0):

What I actually did was to get the List<> of the selected items from the database and then use a `Random` object, using the `size()` of the return list as the `maxInt`. And yes I did check for nulls.

```
Dao dao = getHelper().getObjectDao();
PreparedQuery<Object> query = dao.queryBuilder().[query].prepare();
Object object = null;
List<Object> resultList = dao.query(query);
if(resultList != null && resultList.size() > 0){
    Random random = new Random();
    int selected = random.nextInt(resultList.size() - 1);
    object = resultList.get(selected);
}
```

Comment: Wow.  This is a lot more expensive and for large result sets, can produce a prohibitive amount of IO.  Did you try my solution?

Comment: Gray, it's remarkable that your answer is not the accepted answer. I'd vote for your answer as you know ormlite best.

Comment: Actually, John, it would be only fair to grant Gray the "accepted answer", as he is the creator of ORMLITE and you asked the question.

Comment: I hope I get points for good answers @Christine, not just because I'm the ORMLite author.  :-)

Comment: I agree, Gray. You do get points for your good answer. In this case, I made the point so moderators who may not be qualified to judge your answer, know what this is about. Apparently, someone took action. I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
dao.queryBuilder().orderByRaw("RANDOM()").queryForFirst();
```